# Bold and italic Hindi Lohit Devanagri fonts in latex with Polyglossia

Tags: luatex, overleaf, polyglossia, hindi, devanagari

I am trying to typeset in Hindi using Lulalatex/Polyglossia with Lohit Devanagari fonts in Overleaf. There are no default bold and italics font for Lohit Devanagari. Hence I am using Fakebold and Fakeslant to define new fonts. Still, my fonts are non-bold and non-italics. Here is MWE. Why should it not work? What should be the correct way of achieving this? Any help is appreciated.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hindi} 
\setotherlanguage{english} 
\newfontfamily\hindifont[Script=Devanagari]{Lohit Devanagari}
\newfontfamily\hindifontit[Script=Devanagari, AutoFakeSlant=-0.15]{Lohit Devanagari}
\newfontfamily\hindifontbf[Script=Devanagari, AutoFakeBold=4]{Lohit Devanagari}
\begin{document}

नमस्ते

\textbf{नमस्ते}

\textit{नमस्ते}


Namaste
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The italic and bold fonts are not separate families but different shapes in the same family. Therefore you would need:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hindi} 
\setotherlanguage{english} 
\newfontfamily\hindifont[Script=Devanagari, AutoFakeBold=4, AutoFakeSlant=-0.15]{Lohit Devanagari}
\begin{document}

नमस्ते

\textbf{नमस्ते}

\textit{नमस्ते}


Namaste
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1, but logically I don't get this. E.g., there have been cases where I require the same font for two different languages (having different linguistic sets in the font obviously). So I have `\newfontfamily\abclang[Language=abc]{foo}` and `\newfontfamily\xyzlang[Language=xyz]{foo}` in the preamble and in the body, I write `{\xyz xyz}`, `{\abc abc}`. If this works, then why not OP's code? Undoubtedly your way is more economical, but _*why*_ is what OP doing not working is not very clear to me. Some explanation on this would be appreciated.

Comment: In polyglossia `\abclang` is a magic name which is loaded as a font when language `abc` is selected. That's why `\newfontfamily\abclang[Language=abc]{foo}` allows you to select the font with `{\abc abc}` (if `abc` is a language) and that's also why `\hindilang` works in this code (`hindi` is selected as the language in the preamble, so `\hindilang` is loaded as the font).

Comment: What the OP tried is something different, they appended additional characters (`it` or `bf`) to the name `\hindilang` to form e.g. `\hindilangit` and then still expected this to have a special meaning, but then the name no longer had the form `\<language>lang` and was therefore just a random font family. This does work when appending `tt` or `sf` because `\<language>langtt` and `\<language>langsf` also have special meaning in polyglossia, but there's no reason why any characters should be special there.

Comment: This works, Thanks @MarcelKrüger