bold and italics in sanskrit
I'm trying to use Latex for typing a document with sanskrit and english together. I have the template show in this exchange.
However, I'm unable to get bold and italics for both english and sanskrit portion of the document. Also, I get date below the title, which I want to get rid. Any help. I'm using XeLatex on Ubuntu. Here, the MWE.
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2cm,right=2cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{sanskrit}
\setmainfont[Script=Devanagari]{Lohit Devanagari}
\title {भगवद्गीता}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Chapter1}
\textit{Verse1} \\
\begin{center}
   \textit{सञ्जय उवाच} \\
   \begin{sanskrit}
      \bf{धर्मक्षेत्रे कुरुक्षत्रे समवेता युयुत्सवः । \\
          मामकाः पाण्डवाश्चैव किमकर्वत सञ्जय}
   \end{sanskrit}
\end{center}
\end{document}



https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/697811/128462

I don't think Lohit Devanagari provides true bold and italic fonts. You would have to use some other font, such as Noto Devanagari.

off-topic: do not use two-letter font switches in latex! and remember, if you do use them e.g. with plain, that they do not take arguments. also don't break lines with \\  outside special environments (center is fine, but the break right before it shouldn't be done that way)

\date{} to get rid of the date ;).

apart from the fonts for Devanagari you have the incorrect syntax \bf{...}  the command \bf is not defined by default in latex, and in classes where it is defined from compatibility with documents from the 1980s it would be {\bf ....} the latex command is \textbf{...}

@ApoorvPotnis oh sorry I just noticed that your comment links to Marcel giving same information as my answer (with probably better slant) close this one as duplicate?

The font is only available in one style although the font can be automatically transformed to give a bold or slanted appearance, especially for slanted/italic I fear this may be culturally inappropriate but as I can not read this script I can not tell.

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont[Script=Devanagari,AutoFakeBold,AutoFakeSlant]{Lohit-Devanagari.ttf}

\begin{document}

सञ्जय उवाच

\textit{सञ्जय उवाच}

\textbf{सञ्जय उवाच}


\end{document}

